# CSS Animation not working on Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have an image caption that fades in via CSS animation. It works on Safari and Firefox but it won't run on Chrome. I've tested it on both a 28" iMac and a 13" Macbook Pro, both with the same result. I also reset the browser settings so I believe it's something in the CSS or possibly the jQuery. I have also tried reinstalling these plugins and restoring them to the default with no luck.

If anyone could help with why this is happening, it would be greatly appreciated!

[Website](http://thegemfoundation.com/dev)

CSS:

```
.flexslider .flex-active-slide .flex-caption {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-animation-name: reset, fadeIn;
-moz-animation-name: reset, fadeIn;
-o-animation-name: reset, fadeIn;
-ms-animation-name: reset, fadeIn;
animation-name: reset, fadeIn;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-moz-animation-duration: 2s;
-o-animation-duration: 2s;
-ms-animation-duration: 2s;
animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
-o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
animation-timing-function: ease-in;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0, .5s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0, .5s;
-o-animation-delay: 0, .5s;
-ms-animation-delay: 0, .5s;
animation-delay: 0, .5s;
}
```

[jQuery (Flexslider)](http://thegemfoundation.com/graham/javascripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js)

Comment: Just visited the website on a Lenovo with Windows 8, and it worked fine in chrome.

Comment: Works fine on my ASUS running Windows 8 in Chrome as well

Comment: it worked fine on chrome on a macbook pro for me as well. you probably just need to clear your cache(tools -> clear browsing data).

Comment: I've cleared my cache, disabled all extensions, reset chrome to it's original settings and restarted the computer. It still won't work on either macs.

Comment: Tested on 15" retina macbook chrome (32.0.1700.107) - no problems for me.